# WordPress admin buttons are not working, can't add new product

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: firefox console erros]

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More] 
>   load-scripts.php:237:114  Woocommerce Wordrpess.

[load-scrips.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpnmn.png)

[image: load-scrips.php]

I do not know what happened, it was working fine yesterday. I lost admin button hover effects, and add new product buttons are not responding at all. however, I want to add a new post, category; everything is working fine.
Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Try to find out where the ')' is missing your load-scripts.php. It will probably prevent jQuery from being loaded. Or please show us your load-scripts.php.

Comment: Some plugin is breaking it, deactivate the all the plugins and check

Comment: I did not find anything like that in wp-admin/load-scripts.php, however, the blue highlighted line starting with $closeBtn=jQuery seems to have the issue.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will take backup and delete wp-admin and wp-includes folder and paste wp-admin and wp-includes from the downloaded new wordpress framework folder.

Note: Do not delete or change wp-content folder

Comment: Did not work... It's only happening on "add new product" admin page. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

**So I found a fix on facebook**
I added `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` to /wp-config.php

and at the bottom of the file (just above the “require_once” line

Thanks!